# Outlook 2007 - Copy emails to Sharepoint lists

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

So, I've managed to add Sharepoint lists in Outlook. And I want to copy a bunch of emails to some of those folders. But Outlook says that the folder is protected. Isn't is possible to copy emails directly to these Sharepoint lists via Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You can only copy mails into Discussion Board lists from Outlook, see here for an example: http://blog.mikehacker.net/2011/05/02/drag-and-drop-email-from-outlook-to-sharepoint/

Comment: The only thing about Discussion Board lists I had a problem with was it did not take any messages which contain security content such as digital signatures or encryption. If you use a general SharePoint list, it will accept message files .msg of any kind. Unfortunately when you look for message files in the SharePoint list, the mail headers such as sender, date sent, etc are not readily viewable without opening the message first. I don't know if there is a way to get SharePoint to pull that information off the file?

Comment: We changed our implementation completly and are now using an Outlook addin to copy messages to a doc lib and in the process extract metadata (to, from, date etc.) and store that in custom fields on the doc lib. Works like a charm!